# How to add a Worksheet function in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use a built-in function in a Google Apps script. 
Something similar to VBA `WorksheetFunction`
How can I achieve that?

For example, how to include in the script:

```
var foo=DATEVALUE(mydate);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#getting_started) on the Google Developers website has all the information you'd need to create functions.

In short, you need to go the Script Editor (Tools -> Script Editor) inside the spreadsheet, write the function and then access it from your spreadsheet cells.

Comment: I don't want to create a custom function. I want to use a built-in function in a script.

Comment: Sorry, built-in functions are not available inside the Apps Script environment. You can however replicate most of the functionality with Apps Script itself.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same challenge.

My conceptual solution is the following:

1. Create a Spreadsheet with a cell (or cells) specifically devoted to the inputs of the built-in function, and another cell containing the built-in formula and it's result.
2. From a Spreadsheet embedded Google Apps Script, link to the spreadsheet and the two ranges: 1) through the first link feed the values into the input cell (or cells); 2) through the second link retrieve the result of the formula.
3. Every time you need the result of a built-in formula in the Google Apps Script, from the code send the desire inputs to the spreadsheet and retrieve the result of the built-in formula.

I have tried this for regular scripts. It does not work for user defined functions. I needed the =NORMSINV() function in a user defined function, and had no other option than to import code into my script...

As said, it's a conceptual solution, not a practical one. I am certain this is extremely expensive in terms of script efficiency.

Bear in mind the Google Apps Script is base on JavaScript 1.6, which has a lot of functionality in itself. You may want to check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: that's a bit ackward, but I guess it solves the problem, I had tried it myself when struggling with date formats. Thanks for your help!