# Google Sheets Script: Passing function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a script in Google Sheets:

```
/**
 * @param {array} input A row or a column.
 * @param {function} condition A function returning bool.
 * @return The last value in the input satisfying the condition.
 * @customfunction
 */
function GetLastGoodValIn1DArray(input, condition) {
  // realization ...
}
```

When I'm trying to call this function with the next arguments:

```
=GetLastGoodValIn1DArray(D11:H11;ISNUMBER)
```

I'm getting the next error:

> Error
>
> TypeError: #NAME? is not a function, but a string. (line 26).

Obviously 'ISNUMBER' interpreted as a string. But how to pass it as a function?

Comment: The formula is not written properly. Try `=GetLastGoodValIn1DArray(D11:H11;ISNUMBER(something))` where something could be a value or a cell reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not is possible to access internal google sheets functions from a script according to this [old google docs forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/1Vab4UYYG_0) and this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235239/how-to-add-a-worksheet-function-in-google-apps-script).

Note that even google sheets internal functions can't take functions as parameters. For example, the internal function [SUBTOTAL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649), instead of taking the function directly, takes in a numerical code that corresponds to the desired function.

The best I can think of is to build your own WorksheetFunction object like excel has for vba. That could be an object map that takes in an string and returns a function you wrote. For example:

```
var worksheetFunction = {
  isnumber: function (x) {
    return !isNaN(x);
  }
};
```

> ***Another Note***: `ISNUMBER` isn't passed as a string to your custom function. Google sheets first calculates it as an error and then
>   passes the string `#NAME?` to your custom function. You can see this by using the formula
>   `=type(ISNUMBER)`, which returns 16 (the code for an error) also in
>   your custom function `condition === "#NAME?"` will evaluate to true.